# why use of 1uf capacitors in max232 ic, why does not use 10uf capacitor in max232 ic.?

Tags: capacitor, max232

I have use 1uf capacitor in max232 circuit
c1=1uf (pin 1 and 3)
c2=1uf (pin 4 and 5)
c3=1uf (pin 2 and vcc)
c4=1uf (pin 6 and gnd)
c5=0.1uf (pin vcc and gnd)

why this type of values used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if datasheet says 1uF for the charge pump then that is the best value it works with the given frequency of the charge pump. Higher capacitance charges more slowly so the charge pump would need slower frequency or it would take longer for the pumped voltage to settle. Lower capacitances would charge too fast and can not transfer enough charge per clock cycle, so the voltage would droop under load. There is a difference between MAX232 and MAX232A, the former needs 1uF capacitors while the latter only needs 100nF capacitors.

Answer (score 2):

Because those are the values the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/max232) says it was designed for:

[image]

It doesn't say why, and it doesn't show the internal circuitry so you really have no choice but to follow its recommendation.

---

The capacitors are used to generate the voltages needed for true [RS232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Voltage_levels) operation.

The positive output is boosted to 7 volts to make up for line and load losses.

The required negative voltage is generated from the given 5 volt supply.  It is inverted to give a negative output at about 7 volts.

The internal boost and inverter circuitry is intended for use with 1 microfarad external capacitors.  It might also work with higher (or lower values) but the manufacturer doesn't mention that option or give you any information you would need if you were to use a different capacitor value.

It might appear to function if you use different values, but then generate bad signals at random because the charge pumps couldn't hold the output voltage steady.

Answer (score 0):

The correct capacitor for reduced conducted noise across Vdd,Vss is also 1uF .

This older technology also has higher switch Ron ~300 ohms .  If you upgrade to Max201 then they can all be 0.1 uF caps .